# nth-child(number) Selector for css not getting applied

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place 3 rectangular div of 200*200 inside 600*600 div. with a separation of 25 pixel . my first code works fine.but when i try to apply nth-child(1) and nth-child(2) it is not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/user1989/L20fn90L/

if i change the style part as

```
#two-parent :nth-child(0){
margin-top:25px;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color : black;

float:left;

}
#two-parent :nth-child(1){
margin-top:25px;
position:relative;
width:200px;
height:200px;
background-color : orange;
margin-left:25px;
float:left;
}
```

The child selector is not getting applied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using div as a child container then these CSS declarations should do the work:

```
#two-parent div:nth-child(1) { /** :nth-child(1) for 1st child  **/
  /** Declaration **/
}
#two-parent div:nth-child(2) { /** :nth-child(2) for 2nd child **/
  /** Declaration **/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to select an element like @Den said:
Try it: https://jsfiddle.net/3bpjxec0/

```
#box .b:nth-child(1) b {
  font-size:14px;
}
```